# Seed method to populate data from existing table in EF code first

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF code first, and I need to split a table and add columns as required. And I want the all data to be preserved and transfer some data from the existing table to the new one.

So for that, I have created another model and in the migration file, after the CreateTable() method, I am adding a

```
Sql("INSERT INTO NewTable(pkID, col1, col2,...) SELECT NEWID(), col, col2, ... FROM OldTable");
```

statement to populate some column data, and after that I am adding the DropColumn statements to drop the columns from OldTable, that are transfered.

I don't know whether it is the best way or the Seed() method can do it easily or any other way to do it.

Please suggest.
Thanks.